# How to bypass alert message when core data file is corrupted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

If core data gets corrupted, this may happen in some scenarios as a user opens the .sqlite file and do some invalid changes.

I get the following alert message (which comes somewhere from internal framework or OS, that I am not aware of) :

[image]

I put breakpoints, after this alert the control goes to the following method. Here `dict` is set with some text, which is again shown to user as an alert.

I commented few statements and added a method `deleteAll` that would silently delete all the three files.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext //1
{
    if (_managedObjectContext) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }
    
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
//        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
//        [dict setValue:@"Failed to initialize the store. \n\nResetting..." forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
//        [dict setValue:@"There was an error building up the data file." forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
//        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
//        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        
        [self deleteAll];
        
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

-(void)deleteAll{
    NSURL *url = [self applicationFilesDirectory];
    NSArray *files = @[@"CoreDataInput.sqlite", @"CoreDataInput.sqlite-shm", @"CoreDataInput.sqlite-wal"];
    
    for (NSString *file in files) {
        NSURL *tempUrl =[url URLByAppendingPathComponent:file];
        NSLog(@"url is : %@", tempUrl);

        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]removeItemAtURL:tempUrl
                                                 error:&error];
    }
}
```

After this I am again creating the core data files. So far so good.

My requirement is **not to show the above warning/alert**. How to remove that warning, is there any API / notification etc to bypass it.

*May be this won't happen very similar as above in OSX, but there would be some other message.*

Comment: what is in [self persistentStoreCoordinator]?

Comment: @jimpic: That is auto generated code, you can create a coredata project and check. However it does this *Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. (The directory for the store is created, if necessary.)*

Answer (score 3):

I find the answer :)

I removed this `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];` statements which is inside the following auto generated method. Now even if the file is not found or is corrupted, it silently creates a new one. Ofcourse all data is removed, as I don't want them.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    ...
        if (!ok) {
            //[[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
            return nil;
        }
    } else {
        if (![properties[NSURLIsDirectoryKey] boolValue]) {
            ...
            //[[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
            return nil;
        }
    }

...
        //[[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```